# How to know if the JSON Data has the key in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

What is the proper way to know if the key exists in a JSON structure, by using the library of Newtonsoft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally use this method of checking:

```
    Dim JArray = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse("JSON")
    If JArray("Key") IsNot Nothing Then

    End If
```

But there may be other ways to do so. This way just tries to grab a value and if it cannot find it, will return `Nothing` which can be checked against :)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I cannot test it anymore, maybe someone will confirm this.

Comment: It's an old question so it's unlikely, It does work though and it's what I use when needing to retrieve a key :)